# Android - Display data from Adapter in Listview

Tags: android, json, listview, adapter, android-studio-2.1

I've currently got an application that pulls data from a mysql database and displays it in raw JSON format. I'm currently working on pushing this data into a String variable and displaying it on a Listview on a specific activity.
Problem is, when trying to display this data, my Listview is not populating; I'm sure the variable is not empty as the if statement would have captured this.

Here is snippet of MainActivity code:

```
//Methods to grab information from abhandym_DB database
public void getJSON(View view){
new BackgroundTask().execute();
}

public void parseJSON(View view){
if(JSON_String==null){
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "First Get Json", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}else{
    Intent intent = new Intent(this,Test.class);
    intent.putExtra("JSON_Data",JSON_String);
    startActivity(intent);
}
}

class BackgroundTask extends AsyncTask<Void,Void,String>{

    String json_url;

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        json_url = "http://abhandyman.x10host.com/json_get_data.php";
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {
        try {
            URL url = new URL(json_url);
            HttpURLConnection httpURLConnection = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
            InputStream inputSteam = httpURLConnection.getInputStream();
            BufferedReader buffereredReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputSteam));
            StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
            while((JSON_String = buffereredReader.readLine())!=null){
            stringBuilder.append(JSON_String+"\n");
            }
            buffereredReader.close();
            inputSteam.close();
            httpURLConnection.disconnect();
            return stringBuilder.toString().trim();

        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(Void... values) {
        super.onProgressUpdate(values);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        TextView textView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.fragment1_textview_JSONAPPEAR);
        textView.setText(result);
        JSON_String = result;
    }
}
```

Here is the code for my Test.java

```
public class Test extends AppCompatActivity {
String JSON_String;
JSONObject jsonObject;
JSONArray jsonArray;
DataAdapter dataAdapter;
ListView listView;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.test_layout);
    listView = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.test_listView);
    dataAdapter = new DataAdapter(this, R.layout.row_layout);
    listView.setAdapter(dataAdapter);
    JSON_String = getIntent().getExtras().getString("JSON_Data");
    try {
        jsonObject = new JSONObject(JSON_String);
        jsonArray = jsonObject.getJSONArray("server_response");
        int count = 0;
        String jobid,problem,resolution;
        while(count<jsonObject.length()){
            JSONObject JO = jsonArray.getJSONObject(count);
            jobid = JO.getString("jobid");
            problem = JO.getString("problem");
            resolution = JO.getString("resolution");
            Data data = new Data(jobid,problem,resolution);
            dataAdapter.add(data);
            count++;
        }
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

}

Here is the code for my DataAdapter:

```
public class DataAdapter extends ArrayAdapter{
List list = new ArrayList();
public DataAdapter(Context context, int resource) {
    super(context, resource);
}

public void add(Data object) {
    super.add(object);
    list.add(object);
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return list.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    return list.get(position);
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View row;
    row = convertView;
    DataHolder dataHolder;
    if(row == null){
        LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater)this.getContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        row = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.row_layout,parent,false);
        dataHolder = new DataHolder();
        dataHolder.tx_jobid = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.tx_jobid);
        dataHolder.tx_problem = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.tx_problem);
        dataHolder.tx_resolution = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.tx_resolution);
        row.setTag(dataHolder);
    }else{
    dataHolder = (DataHolder)row.getTag();
    }
    Data data = (Data)this.getItem(position);
    dataHolder.tx_jobid.setText(data.getJobid());
    dataHolder.tx_problem.setText(data.getProblem());
    dataHolder.tx_resolution.setText(data.getResolution());
    return row;
}

static class DataHolder{
TextView tx_jobid,tx_problem,tx_resolution;
}
```

}

and here is what it displays when clicking on "Parse JSON" button.

[listView empty after population](https://i.stack.imgur.com/07gnM.jpg)

Any help or advise on why its not displaying would be much appreciated!

Thanks in advance!

Comment: In your method `add()` in adapter. add a method call to refresh the adapter `this.notifyDatasetChanged()`

Comment: That has seemed to work! but not 100%, it only displays 1 of the 4 data entries in my database. When getting the JSON raw data I can clearly see more than 1 entry inside. Any ideas? Thanks for your contribution Adil

Comment: Does it always display the first value? Or the last? Did you confirm that jsonObject.length() returns the correct value?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your problem seems to be here :

```
while(count<jsonObject.length()){
```

you're not looping using the number of array elements but using the number of mapped key:value object which is one (the "server_response") , you have to change this line to :

```
while(count<jsonArray.length()){
```

,

you have just the first element showing because `jsonObject.length()` will return `1` since it have just one element.

from the doc, JSONObject, length() method:

> Returns the number of name/value mappings in this object.

and in your case you have just one name/value mapped (`"server_response":[array items...]`)

Answer (score 0):

Check in Test.java. I think You are setting the adapter to the listview before adding data to it

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.test_layout);
        listView = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.test_listView);
        dataAdapter = new DataAdapter(this, R.layout.row_layout);

        JSON_String = getIntent().getExtras().getString("JSON_Data");
        try {
            jsonObject = new JSONObject(JSON_String);
            jsonArray = jsonObject.getJSONArray("server_response");
            int count = 0;
            String jobid,problem,resolution;
            while(count<jsonObject.length()){
                JSONObject JO = jsonArray.getJSONObject(count);
                jobid = JO.getString("jobid");
                problem = JO.getString("problem");
                resolution = JO.getString("resolution");
                Data data = new Data(jobid,problem,resolution);
                dataAdapter.add(data);
                count++;
            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
         listView.setAdapter(dataAdapter); //change effected
    }
```

Comment: That didn't seem to make any difference :(